# How can mount work with an empty fstab?

Tags: mount, fstab

From the Arch Linux installation guide:

> The /etc/fstab file contains static filesystem information. It defines how storage devices and partitions are to be mounted and integrated into the overall system. It is read by the mount command to determine which options to use when mounting a specific device or partition.

This is why we need to generate that file as a step of the installation process.

So how is it possible for `mount` to mount the root partition in `/mnt` at the very beginning of the installation process, if `fstab` at that point is still empty, since at that point it hasn't been generated yet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/etc/fstab` defines the **default configuration**.  It lists default filesystem/mount point/option combinations.  When you mount a filesystem, if you don’t specify complete parameters and options, `mount` will read the options from your `fstab`.  For example, you can type

```
mount /dev/sda1
```

and `mount` will know where to put it, and you can type

```
mount /mnt/sda1
```

and `mount` will know where to find it.  But if you want to be peculiar, you can type

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sdq17
```

and `mount` will do that.  Similarly, you can specify on the command line that a filesystem should be mounted read-only.  Conversely, you can specify in `/etc/fstab` that a filesystem should be mounted read-only by default, and then override that on the command line.  And you can manually mount filesystems that aren’t in `/etc/fstab` at all.

Also, `/etc/fstab` identifies which filesystems are automatically mounted at boot time; they are mounted with their specified default options.

But also, just as you can type `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sda1`, a program can execute `mount` with a complete argument list, and then (in principle) `mount` doesn’t need to access `/etc/fstab` at all.  And the operating system automagically knows where its root partition is, and automatically mounts the root filesystem *very* early in the boot process.  In fact, if the OS needed `/etc/fstab` to be accessible before it could do mounts, we’d have a chicken-and-egg problem, since `/etc` isn’t accessible *until* the root filesystem has been mounted.  The root partition is included in `/etc/fstab` for the other reason that `/etc/fstab` exists — to give `fsck` a list of things to check.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed (better!) answer.  I'm deleting mine because of the duplication here, please remove the link to mine in yours.

Comment: Ok, the Arch wiki was a bit confusing on this point then :)

Comment: Something still confuses me. How do mount options for / specified in fstab apply if fstab is not used for mounting it? (e.g. if you enable discard for your ssd)